# jQuery to add a hashtag to next page that loads?

Tags: jquery

Is this possible?  I want the very next page that loads to have a hashtag.

I want to do something with the next page only.

Thanks.

Comment: how is a user getting to that next page?

Comment: @ggeiner a form is being submitted via jquery

Comment: Well if it's a form that makes it easier. Add a hidden input to the form whose value is the hashtag you want the next page to display. Then when the next page loads output the form value to somewhere on the new page, and grab it from there in document.ready....basically

Comment: @james - this is great and will work. I was hoping to do something client side so I wouldn't have to mess with the db...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use javascript at all, just add the hashtag to action like so:

```
<form method="post" action="somepage#hashtag">...</form>
```

The form will automatically add the hashtag on page load and you can pick it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just use javascript to add the hashtag to the end of the action attribute of the form tag.

```
var form = $("form.myform");
var currentAction = form.attr('action');
var newAction = currentAction + "#myhash";

form.attr('action', newAction);
```